# SDL2 with OpenglES 1.0/2.0 and IOS 7 orientation issues

Tags: ios, opengl-es, sdl

I am having strange behavior with SDL 2.0.3 and OpenglES 1.0/2.0 under IOS 7.0 simulator.
I have attached a test app to my github repo: https://github.com/sabotage3d/gltest
For simplicity the example is OpenglES 1.0.
When I run my test app I am getting a black screen or sometimes huge offset. When I start rotating the screen I can see there is offset and the arrow is not oriented properly depending on the screen orientation. Another issue is when I keep rotating the screen SDL seems to miss events.

Here is part of the code:

```
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_EGL, 1);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_ES);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 1);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 1);

SDL_DisplayMode displayMode;
SDL_GetDesktopDisplayMode(0, &displayMode);

SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow("Orientation", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,   SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, displayMode.h, displayMode.w, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE | SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);

SDL_GLContext gl = SDL_GL_CreateContext(window);


glGenRenderbuffersOES(1, &m_renderbuffer);
glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, m_renderbuffer);



glGenFramebuffersOES(1, &m_framebuffer);
glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, m_framebuffer);
glFramebufferRenderbufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES,
                             GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_OES,
                             GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES,
                             m_renderbuffer);

glViewport(0, 0, displayMode.h, displayMode.w);

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);

// Initialize the projection matrix.
const float maxX = 2;
const float maxY = 3;
glOrthof(-maxX, +maxX, -maxY, +maxY, -1, 1);

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);


SDL_Event event;

bool done = false;

while (!done)
{


    //Render
    glClearColor(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glPushMatrix();
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

    glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(Vertex), &Vertices[0].Position[0]);
    glColorPointer(4, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(Vertex), &Vertices[0].Color[0]);

    GLsizei vertexCount = sizeof(Vertices) / sizeof(Vertex);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertexCount);

    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    glPopMatrix();

    SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window);


    SDL_PumpEvents();
    while (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
    {

        if (event.type == SDL_WINDOWEVENT && event.window.event == SDL_WINDOWEVENT_RESIZED)
        {
            SDL_Log("Window %d resized to %dx%d",
                    event.window.windowID, event.window.data1,
                    event.window.data2);
        }

        switch (event.type)
        {
            case SDL_QUIT:
                done = true;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know SDL, so I might just be missing something. But you create a renderbuffer, and never allocated storage for it. Shouldn't there be a call to `glRenderbufferStorage()` somewhere? Also, you render to an FBO, but I don't see anything that would show the content of the FBO/renderbuffer on the display.

Comment: It shouldn't be needed as SDL already does it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that SDL already provides all the framebuffer calls removing them fixed my issue.
Also I had to fix the aspect ratio of the camera.

This the code that needs to be removed:

```
glGenRenderbuffersOES(1, &m_renderbuffer);
glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, m_renderbuffer);



glGenFramebuffersOES(1, &m_framebuffer);
glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, m_framebuffer);
glFramebufferRenderbufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES,
                         GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_OES,
                         GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES,
                         m_renderbuffer);
```